# How do SAP and Navision interact with third-party applications?

Tags: sap-erp, microsoft-dynamics-nav, sap-crm

I am developing a business application and, provided that many companies look for integration, I would like to make it "compatible" with business systems like SAP or Navision. What mechanisms do these systems use for importing/exporting/syncing data with third-party applications?

Comment: "would like to make it compatible with SAP or Navision" is like "would like to make it run on Windows and Solaris" - this question in its current form is way too broad for the Q&A format of SO.

Comment: The answer to "would like to make it run on Windows and Solaris" would be, for example, "use Java". I'm just asking if there exists a common approach for exchanging data between SAP/Navision and third-party software.

Comment: "Use an interface." There you go, did that help?

Comment: In our company we make use of IDocs for external systems. Check XI/PI documentation and Netweaver for a better reference. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you nmiranda for a constructive answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist software tools known as EAI (Enterprise Application Integration) whose purpose is to act as middleware to enable the integration of applications across a company.

[Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) is an example of such framework, but there exist many of them. You can find a comparison list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_business_integration_software

As the user [nmiranda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130097/nmiranda) pointed out, in the case of SAP, the framework used for data interchange is [SAP PI (SAP NetWeaver Process Integration)](http://scn.sap.com/community/pi-and-soa-middleware).

I think your question was actually aimed to find this "starting point", wasn't it? I faced the same question some years ago and I also wondered if there was any "standard" interface to integrate applications. In such case, I hope have helped you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll take a look at Apache Camel. It seems it has an extension for SAP NetWeaver.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to integrate with ERP data sources. You can do batch integration where you setup a query that pulls the data from the source ERPs on a scheduled bases. ETL tools like [Informatica](http://www.informatica.com/) and [Talend](http://www.talend.com/) shines on this front.

If you want online data integration when you want live data in your business application then you need to look at Data Virtualization solutions like [Denodo](http://www.denodo.com/), [VirtDB](http://www.virtdb.com/) or [Composite](http://www.compositesw.com/).

Prices, feature sets, performance and flexibility highly differ. One distinguishing factor in my practice is security. Solutions tend to extract data into file system, which makes a problem when sensitive data is extracted. In real projects, implementors usually start a long process replicating the source system security objects in the target application.